# Do WCF and DataContractSerializer serialize CollectionDataContract-decorated collection types differently?

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

I have a really simple customized collection type that inherits from List<> and uses a CollectionDataContract.

When I use DataContractSerializer.WriteObject to serialize it, it respects the CollectionDataContract attribute the way I'd expect; however, when I use it as a return type for a WCF method, I get the default ArrayOfFoo.

I'm wondering if there is some decoration I'm missing in the service contract.

Details:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string BarString { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(Namespace = "")]
[Serializable]
public class FooList : List<Foo> {}
```

If I just instantiate a Foo and then use DataContractSerializer.WriteObject to serialize it, I get what you'd expect:

```
<FooList>
    <Foo>
        <BarString>myString1</BarString>
    </Foo>
</FooList>
```

However, if I have a service with a method like this...

```
[ServiceContract Name = "MyService"]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "foos/")]
    FooList GetAllFoos();
}
```

and then do a GET for http://www.someEndpoint.com/foos/, I get this:

```
<ArrayOfFoo>
    <Foo>
        <BarString>myString1</BarString>
    </Foo>
</ArrayOfFoo>
```

I've also tried specifying Name="MyFooListName" in the CollectionDataContract attribute.  Same results: DataContractSerializer gets the memo; WCF doesn't.

Comment: I think, yes, it convert lists to array.

Comment: You're right that a List gets serialized to an Array if you don't customize the collection type; what I'm trying to figure out is whether there's a way to get WCF to respect my CollectionDataContract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saeed sent me in the right direction: I inadvertently ended up with XmlSerializer, when I had been hoping for DataContractSerializer.

I had ended up with XmlSerializer... well... by asking for it.

In particular, I had decorated methods in my service with the XmlSerializerFormat like this:

```
[ServiceContract Name = "MyService"] 
public interface IMyService 
{ 
    //  ... other stuff ...

    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "foos/", Method = "POST")] 
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    Foo PostAFoo(Foo yourNewFoo);
}
```

I had done this in the hopes of forgiving member order in hand-rolled Foo XML blobs.  Of course, when one does this one ends up with XmlSerializer, not DataContractSerializer.

When I take away the XmlSerializerFormat attribute, problem solved: WCF is now serializing my FooList collection the way I want.

Comment: I didn't test the above code, but it works fine for collection?

Answer (score 2):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx) for detail:

> The DataContractSerializer does not
>   support the programming model used by
>   the XmlSerializer and ASP.NET Web
>   services. In particular, it does not
>   support attributes like
>   XmlElementAttribute and
>   XmlAttributeAttribute. To enable
>   support for this programming model,
>   WCF must be switched to use the
>   XmlSerializer instead of the
>   DataContractSerializer.

So the serialization going to be done by XMLSerializer, and you can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected Generic types while configuring your WCF service? if not then,

right click and go to configuration, then select Generic Type, by default it is arraylist type.